# How to import data using codes in SQLDEV?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to import data using codes in SQLDEV?

I don't want to do it manually. I want to know if there's a way to import from a .csv file using codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code executed in SQL DEVELOPER run on DMBS(your Oracle instalation, the server).
The IDE take your comands(click on schema browser, filters, etc) and transfrom them into commands to the server.

So, you have only Oracle code (SQL and PL/SQL(and Java, etc)) that runs on Server, you don't have code that runs in SQL Developer.

Importing a table can be done:

- Using the wizard from IDE (click on table and then choose import)
- Using the sqlloader on a Oracle client.
- Using External Tables on Server side.